# Add Checkbox to register Form of theme my login - Terms and Conditions

Tags: php, css, authentication, lightbox

First my English not good enough.I will try to explain my problem.

**My problem** is I need a check box on register form. I am not good in Php. I added new lines for register, names, surnames etc. but I nned a check box and I nned to control that if checked or not too. And a link to Terms and Conditions too. when the users click it has to open as light box. is it possible?

[I want something like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mgdUX.jpg)

Answer (score -2, accepted):

```
html=>  <input type="checkbox" name="checkbox1"/>
<input type="checkbox" name="checkbox2"/>
<?php
if(!isset($_POST['checkbox1']))&&(!isset($_POST['checkbox2'])
{
  echo "select term & service also check box";
}?>
```

Comment: Thanks for your help.But really I am poor in PHP. There is a css file in this pluging folder and another register page with php in themes folder. for example when I wanted to add new regester field I add some codes in that php file. the code was

Comment: what are you want plz explain briefly you want that when user register data add in database?

Comment: this is not about database. I just want user click before that checkbox . nothing more. if user didn't click the check box, don't let the registration. the widget already adding database the fields. And ı want a link to read the agreeement like the picture end of main topic.

Comment: this is possible only in javascript

Comment: you understand urdu laguage

Comment: thank you for your helping. And if I just wanted to write a message as a link that open new page.can I do that just in php file.

Comment: in html <a href="link here" >message here</a>  and if you want dynamic msg then message here instead of $variable and $ variable put in form and every time change your msg